# How to search a Python List via Object Attribute?

Tags: python, list

Consider the following python class:

```
class Event(Document):
  name = StringField()
  time = DateField()
  location = GeoPointField()

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name
```

Now I create a list of Events:

```
x = [Event(name='California Wine Mixer'),
  Event(name='American Civil War'),
  Event(name='Immaculate Conception')]
```

Now I want to add only unique events by searching via the event name.
How is this done with the boolean in syntax?

The following is incorrect:

```
a = Event(name='California Wine Mixer')
if a.name in x(Event.name):
  x.append(a)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By unique I think you want something like "if a.name **not** in x(Event.name):", which can be written as

```
if not any(y.name == a.name for y in x):
  ...
```

But if the name acts as an index, it is better to use a dictionary to avoid the O(N) searching time and the more complex interface.

```
event_list = [Event(name='California Wine Mixer'), ...]

event_dict = dict((b.name, b) for b in event_list)
# ignore event_list from now on.

....

a = Event(name='California Wine Mixer')
event_dict.setdefault(a.name, a)
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant. Thanks!